# Where is the max?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

Code:

```
a = np.array([[33,77,43],[32,33,55],[56,68,43],[45,45,67],[33,23,5]])
b=a.T
p=np.array([12,16,10,14,15])
def eachsales(position,price):
    print('each salesman total amount',np.sum((position*price),axis=1))
    i=np.where(np.sum((position*price),axis=1)==np.max(np.sum((position*price),axis=1)))
    print('the amount of salesman',i,'is the highest')
eachsales(b,p)
```

I found out the maximum and I knew where it is.

It told me it is at `array([1]` ,but I hope it can output 1 (numeric).

And if it is "1" ,  print "sales A".If it is "2", print "sales B",so on.

> each salesman total amount [2593 3107 2839]
>
> the amount of salesman (array([1], dtype=int64),) is the highest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `np.where()` for this. Instead use the function `np.argmax()`, it returns the index directly. Try the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import string

a = np.array([[33,77,43],[32,33,55],[56,68,43],[45,45,67],[33,23,5]])
b = a.T

p = np.array([12,16,10,14,15])

def eachsales(position,price):
   print('each salesman total amount',np.sum((position*price),axis=1))

   i = np.argmax(np.sum((position*price),axis=1))
   print('the amount of salesman','Sales %s'%string.ascii_uppercase[i],'is the highest')

eachsales(b,p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import numpy as np
import string
a = np.array([[33,77,43],[32,33,55],[56,68,43],[45,45,67],[33,23,5]])
b=a.T
p=np.array([12,16,10,14,15])
def eachsales(position,price):
   print('each salesman total amount',np.sum((position*price),axis=1))
   i=np.where(np.sum((position*price),axis=1)==np.max(np.sum((position*price),axis=1)))
   print('the amount of salesman','Sales %s'%string.ascii_uppercase[i[0]-1],'is the highest')
eachsales(b,p)
```

Output:

```
each salesman total amount [2593 3107 2839]
the amount of salesman Sales A is the highest
```